# Authenticate to Google Cloud text-to-speech API using native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to migrate my application from NodeJS to browser. However, I can't seem to find up-to-date examples of how to authenticate to the Google Cloud Platform in native JavaScript. In NodeJS I was using a service account key to authenticate, but as I understand it, you cannot use a service account key in the browser. My current code:

```js
function AuthenticateToGoogleCloud() {
  handleClientLoad();

  /**
   * Set required API keys and check authentication status.
   */
  function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(CREDS["credentials"][0]["gcloud"]["GC_API_KEY"]);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
  }

  /**
   * Authorize Google API.
   */
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        client_id: CREDS["credentials"][0]["gcloud"]["GC_CLIENT_ID"],
        scope: CREDS["credentials"][0]["gcloud"]["GC_SCOPES"],
        immediate: true,
      },
      handleAuthResult
    );
  }

  /**
   * Handle authorization.
   */
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    console.log(authResult);
    initializeApi();
  }

  /**
   * Load the Google Cloud API.
   */
  function initializeApi() {
    gapi.client.load("texttospeech", "v1");
  }
}
```

When I run this snippet I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setApiKey')

Presumably because the example I got it from is outdated. How can I authenticate to the modern Google Cloud Platform using native JavaScript and with no prompt to a user?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. A secondary option is to [upvote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you feel it is useful for you. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

> Is there any way for me to call the `SynthesizeSpeech` endpoint without utilizing OAuth?

Using Javascript, you must use OAuth. As shown in the Text-to-Speech [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/text/synthesize), the `SynthesizeSpeech` method requires the following OAuth scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`.

---

You should use the [Google OAuth Library](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow), instead of the old authentication method.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#obtainingaccesstokens) you can review the *steps that show how your application interacts with Google's OAuth 2.0 server to obtain a user's consent to perform an API request on the user's behalf.* Note that *your application must have that consent before it can execute a Google API request that requires user authorization.*

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way to make an API request in browser JavaScript without there being a user present to grant consent? Even with an API like the Text-To-Speech API that doesn't access user information?

Comment: As shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries#setting_up_authentication), _to run the client library, you must first set up authentication_. As explained on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73040055/13171940), _there might be libraries or examples only to use on the client side as well, but doing this client side is not likely to be a great decision. The reason is that ... you will need to send your credentials to the API and by doing this on the client side you will be basically leaking your credentials to everyone in the world._

Comment: I've viewed that answer before and tried for a long time to get that solution to work. I believe it ended up failing because the API request is looking for an access_token, not an API key. This is why I've been looking for ways to retrieve an access_token, however I can't use OAuth because there is no user present to grant consent to my app, and it does not access user data in any way. Is there any way for me to call the SynthesizeSpeech endpoint without utilizing OAuth?

Comment: As shown in the [TextToSpeech](documentation), the `SynthesizeSpeech` method requires the following OAuth scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`. You could invoke this method using NodeJS or other backend languages as shown in the [Text-to-Speech client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) documentation.

Comment: @GJKamClark I have updated the answer in accordance to usage of the `SynthesizeSpeech` method with Javascript